# Accept Taps in UIContextMenu Preview Provider

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

**tl;dr:** How do I accept taps on a button within a `UIContextMenuContentPreviewProvider` view controller?

I'm presenting a custom preview controller for a `UIContextMenu`, set via `UIContextMenuContentPreviewProvider` in my `UIContextMenuConfiguration` initializer. The view displays as expected with a button, but tapping it simply dismisses the preview, with no touches being captured by the button. Is that an inherent limitation of the preview API, or is there something I'm missing to enable interaction?

Here's a rough example of the code creating the preview:

```
return UIContextMenuConfiguration(
    identifier: messageId.value as NSString,
    previewProvider: nil,
    previewProvider: {
        let viewController = UIViewController()
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = .green
        
        let button = UIButton(type: .infoLight)
        button.addAction(UIAction(handler: { _ in
            print("Button")                
        }), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        button.sizeToFit()
        
        viewController.view.addSubview(button)
        button.center = viewController.view.center
        
        return viewController
    },
    actionProvider: {_ in
        return UIMenu(title: "", children: reactionOptions)
    }
)
```